# add more elemens in a row in ListView- Android

Tags: java, listview, android-studio

I have an app that allows me to add some houses after i click on a button. I'm using a list View to display this, but i need to add 4 houses in a single row. when i click the button, it adds the houses in a new row, not in the same row. Which is the code for adding more elements in a single row in a ListView?

this is my ListViewAdapter :

```
package com.example.andraripan.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by andraripan on 3/2/17.
 */

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> animals;
    private ArrayList<Integer> houses;
    private Activity activity;



    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> animals, ArrayList<Integer> houses) {
        super();
        this.animals = animals;
        this.houses = houses;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return animals.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {

        return animals.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView imgViewHouse;
        public TextView txtViewTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder view;

        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            view = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row,null);

            view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            view.imgViewHouse = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);





            convertView.setTag(view);

        }
        else
        {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        view.txtViewTitle.setText(animals.get(position));
        view.imgViewHouse.setImageResource(houses.get(position));



        return convertView;
    }
```

}

For one animal :

```
 Cow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(coins >=15 ) {
                    animals.add("Cows"+ "");
                    houses.add(R.drawable.house);

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    coins-=15;
                    Coins.setText(String.valueOf(coins));
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(c, "Insufficient funds!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: As per my understanding, u need a button in the first row and on the button click 4 houses should be displayed in the first row itself, on the right side of the button... Am i right ????

Comment: I wasn't so clear in my description.. For example, i have 3 kinds of animals.. Foxes, Wolves and Hippos. In the first row i've added with a button a house for Foxes. When i click again on that button, to add another house in that row, it puts my house on the second row, not after the first house.. I don't know how to add more houses in a sigle row..

Comment: You need to post your code about OnClickListener.

Comment: I've posted it now :D I was thinking to use a GridView instead, it's ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is because your houses is a list that is displayed vertically in a listview. When you add a house, you are adding it to the next row in the listview.

I'd suggest making a custom row layout and custom adapter to manage it. Then when you click a row you can return that row's id and add a house to the view with the specific id.

I'm pretty new compared to the hardcore programmers here so I can't give ya solid code and also I'm not allowed to comment. I hope this helps steer you in the right direction at least.